# Problems reshaping an array in TF

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm passing in a [64,240] tf.array.
I want to reshape this to a [64,10,24] tf.array.
I've tried various different methods but I always get the same error.

... raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (64, 240) must have rank 1

The code fails at: 
self.x_expand[i] = tf.reshape(self.input_x[i],[num_classes,data_size])

I guess i'm making a basic mistake, hopefully someone can point out what it is...

A larger fragment of the code is:

class CNN(object):

```
def __init__(
  self, sequence_length, num_classes, data_size,
  filter_sizes, num_filters, l2_reg_lambda=0.0, batch_size=64):

    # Placeholders for input, output and dropout
    self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, sequence_length], name="input_x")
    self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_classes], name="input_y")
    self.dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("reshaping"):
        self.x_expand = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_classes,data_size], name="expand_x")
        for i in range(batch_size):
            self.x_expand[i] = tf.reshape(self.input_x[i],[num_classes,data_size]) 
        self.x_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.x_expanded, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want `self.x_expand` to be the input reshaped I think the following might be more appropriate:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("reshaping"):
    self.x_expand = tf.reshape(self.input_x, [batch_size, num_classes, data_size])
```

Two things of note:

1. Did not use a `tf.placeholder` for `self.x_expand`. Placeholders are meant for feeding input from the user, but here it seems what you really wanted was to reshape existing feeds
2. Did not change shape on a per-element basis, but rather with a single operation.

NB: I was unable to reproduce the error message you saw, possibly because we're using different versions of TensorFlow and there have been changes to the error message reporting in recent versions. I am using 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```html
self.x_expand = tf.reshape(self.input_x, [batch_size, num_classes,data_size]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.  This has solved the problem. I'll also look to update tensorflow.